# Как передать файлы REST API yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, rest

Нужно оформить отправку и сохранение файлов (изображений) на сервере с помощью метода POST (и PUT  (или PATCH, есть вообще разница? (и если есть, то какая?)), но сначала хочу разобраться с POST).

Сейчас делаю так, но это не работает:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    unset($actions['delete'], $actions['put']);
    unset($actions['create']);
    return $actions;
}

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new $this->modelClass;
    $juxtapose = new Juxtapose();
    if ($model->save()){
        $juxtapose->loadImages($model->id);
    }

    return "error";

    return new ActiveDataProvider ([
        'query' => Product::find()->where(['id' => $model->id])
    ]);
}
```

...хотя до `"error"` доходит.

Есть готовые методы в модели, которые обрабатывают файл и сохраняют на диск `(loadImages)`, но как их принимать в контроллере?

```
public function loadImages($id)
{
    $this->image =  UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');
    if (!$this->image || !$this->validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($this->image as $image) {
        static::newImages($id, $image);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:**

поменял это `getInstances($this, 'image');` на это `getInstancesByName('image');` и все заработало.

так же переписал экшен :

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new $this->modelClass;
    $model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '');
    if ($model->save()) {
        $model->loadImages();
    }
    return new ActiveDataProvider ([
        'query' => Product::find()->where(['id' => $model->id])
    ]);
}
```

и метод класса, после перемещения в модель `product` :

```
public function loadImages()
{
    $this->image =  UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');
    if (!$this->image || !$this->validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($this->image as $image) {
        Juxtapose::newImages($this->id, $image);
    }
    return true;
}
```